# Firebase login pre-built UI not showing Sign in with Email button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase's pre-built login UI for my app's authentication and had it all working for a while using Facebook, Google, and email/password auth.
Then for some odd reason the Sign in with Email button disappeared on every device I test with.

Here's a shot of the device:
[image]

And here are the directions to enable email login from the Firebase docs:
[image]

Which is exactly what I did:
[image]

Here's the code I'm using to show the Login screen:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            FUIGoogleAuth(),
            FUIFacebookAuth(),
            ]
        authUI!.providers = providers

        self.showLoginScreen()
    }

func showLoginScreen() {
    authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
    self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func authPickerViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth) -> FUIAuthPickerViewController {
    return LoginViewController(authUI: authUI)
}
```

And here's my subclass for the login screen in order to customize it (eventually):

```
class LoginViewController: FUIAuthPickerViewController {

override init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?, authUI: FUIAuth) {
    super.init(nibName: "FUIAuthPickerViewController", bundle: bundle, authUI: authUI)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //self.title = ""
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red


}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sharing your piece of code would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my post. The code is really simple and it's directly from the Firebase docs. The only other thing I'm doing is subclassing the login screen in order to customize it, but I haven't made any changes to it, yet, other than trying to set a background color, which was working, too, but stopped working as well.

Comment: Set authUI.delegate to self to receive callback messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After I updated my pods, I had to explicitly include pod FirebaseUI/Email in my pod file whereas before I didn't need it.
Including that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case after I included the `pod 'FirebaseUI/Email'`, I had to update my providers array as well:

```
        let providers = [FUIGoogleAuth(), FUIEmailAuth()]

        authUI?.providers = providers
```